# How to Truncate a postgreSQL table with conditions

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to truncate a PostgreSQL Table with some conditions.

- Truncate all the data in the table and just let the data of the last 6 months

For that i have written this **Query**

```
select distinct  datecalcul
from Table   
where datecalcul  > now() - INTERVAL '6 months' 
order by  datecalcul asc
```

How could I add **the truncate clause**?

Answer (score 1):

`TRUNCATE` does not support a WHERE condition. You will have to use a `DELETE` statement.

```
delete from the_table
where ...
```

---

If you want to get rid of old ("expired") rows efficiently based on a timestamp, you can think about [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE). Then you can just drop the old partitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Is the internal case correct to keep just the 6 last months ?  is there a better way to do that ?

Comment: @Kakoo16: you could use partitioning to quickly get rid of old rows - but you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: Okey thanks ! is there a differnece between 'months' & 'month' in the INTERVAL clause ? i really don't get it

Comment: How to let the data of 6 months and get delete the other Data  `delete from Table where d_datecalcul  > now() - INTERVAL '6 months' `   IS this a correct query ?